# How to sort text file with header in nodejs

Tags: node.js, sorting, child-process, spawn

I have a function that sorts text files that works fine if there is no header but in a file with a header, the header is getting sorted with the rest of the file.  Is there a way to ignore headers or keep it at the top?

Sort function

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var fs = require('fs');

var sortFile = function(dir, file, type) {
    var sortProcess = spawn('sort', [file]);
    sortProcess.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(dir + '/' + type + '_sorted.txt', { flags: 'a' });

        sortProcess.stdout.pipe(fileStream);

        sortProcess.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
            reject(err);
        });
        sortProcess.on('close', function (code) {
            resolve();
        });
    });
}

module.exports.sortFile = sortFile;
```

Comment: Hard to answer without any content. Can you provide an example? What does your "header" look like?

Comment: The file is a comma delimited text file.  The header is "Field1","Field2","Field3","Field4"

Comment: Looks like a regular csv file and `sort` - not node related. Some bad news: you have to know (and pass an argument) if the first line is a header, when there are files without a header. Have a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/345076/sorting-csv-file-by-first-column-ignoring-header/345137#345137